# jQuery fixed navbar that shrinks to a smaller size on scroll is being super buggy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When using a combination of jQuery and CSS to trigger my navbar to shrink on scroll, it get's buggy when you scroll back up to a certain position, I have linked a video as an example.

I have tried two different methods. The first is using $(window).scrollTop) with an if statement and a series of .addClass and .removeClass. The second thing I have tried is using $(window).scrollTop) with a series of .css dynamic style modifications. Both of these attempts render the same end result that is shown in this video https://youtu.be/YXKsrL1cghs .

My first jQuery attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 40) {
            $(".navbar").removeClass("py-5");
            $(".navbar").addClass("compressed");
        } else {
            $(".navbar").addClass("py-5");
            $(".navbar").removeClass("compressed");
        }
    });
});
```

My second jQuery attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 40) {
            $(".navbar").css({ "padding-top": "10px" });
            $(".navbar").css({ "padding-bottom": "10px" });
        } else {
            $(".navbar").css({ "padding-top": "3rem" });
            $(".navbar").css({ "padding-bottom": "3rem" });
        }
    });
});
```

My CSS:

```
.navbar.compressed {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

My expected results would be a smooth scrolling fixed navbar that shrinks to a smaller size after scrolling beyond a certain point.

What actually occurs is that when you scroll down past a certain point, for 20px worth of height, it gets super buggy and starts bouncing up and down. Once you clear those 20 or so px it's perfectly fine, but when you scroll back up it acts the same within those 20px.

Answer (score 0):

When watching the video, I noticed that your `.navbar` has `transition: all .3s`. It could be the reason that when you remove the class `py-5` and add class `compressed`, it triggers the transition twice.

It would be helpful if you can provide the HTML markup and CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

The script is manipulating the DOM quite a lot. I am not sure if this is going to fix your problem but it might be a good idea to only change the classes if the have not yet been applied.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    let navbar = $(".navbar");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 40) {
      if (navbar.hasClass("py-5")) {
        navbar.removeClass("py-5");
        navbar.addClass("compressed");
      }
    } else {
      if (navbar.hasClass("compressed")) {
        navbar.addClass("py-5");
        navbar.removeClass("compressed");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 10000px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .3s
}

.py-5 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.compressed {
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar py-5">Navigation</nav>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but unfortunately, it still does the same thing. I'm starting to wonder if it's just something with chrome that causes it to bug out.

Comment: I am sorry to hear, do you have a published public version of the website available?

Comment: Not yet, I can throw it up though.